# Fetching date and time when report is generated

Tags: asp.net, .net

I want to fetch the date and time when the report is generated in the form of ddMonyyyy-hhmm.
Currently I am using this code
``` string timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-mmm-yyyy"); DateTime date = DateTime.Now; timeStamp += "_" + Convert.ToString(date.Hour) + Convert.ToString(date.Minute);`` sFileName =sFileName+ timeStamp + ".xls"; ``` 
But here the date and year are not getting fetched correctly.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hours and minutes in Format and it will take literals and just use them. Here are a couple examples. See more [here DateTime.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-7.0)

```
var result = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-mmm-yyyy h:mm tt");
```

Standard Output: 
07-17-2023 10:17 AM

```
var result = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-mmm-yyyy_hhmm");
```

Standard Output: 
07-19-2023_1019

```
var result = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmmyyyyhhmm");
```

Standard Output: 
072120231021

As an aside, you may want to use UtcNow, not Now, unless all your users are in the same timezone or you wanted the time from the server.